# Insert deleted records into history table before DELETE using TRIGGER

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview that displays a recordset from a table - Master2.  I want to use gridview to delete records from this table.  Before the delete occurs, I want to insert the record into a history table with a datetimestamp and userid from the person doing the delete.  Is this possible or should I simply build out the fields with a series of drop down boxes and a single button?

Comment: Have you considered doing this fully on the database side? Like a Delete Trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use a `FOR DELETE` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName    
ON TableName  
FOR DELETE    
AS     
BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO HistoryTable(Col1, Col2, Col3)  
    SELECT Col1, GETDATE(), Col3  
    FROM TableName  
    WHERE DeletedRecordID IN (SELECT DeletedRecordID FROM TableName)     
END
```

Comment: This is excellent.  Is there a way to use the parameters that were selected in the delete statement on my form?  Also, I have a separate parameter that is a reason code that I would like to insert into the new table.  Is this possible?  How do I define the parameters?

Comment: can you post the query of your delete statement for a better understanding.

Comment: `DELETE FROM [MasterData2] WHERE [Ad] = @original_Ad AND [Phase] = @original_Phase AND [Page] = @original_Page AND [Page Type] = @original_Page_Type AND [Percent] = @original_Percent AND [Change Type] = @original_Change_Type AND (([UserName] = @original_UserName) OR ([UserName] IS NULL AND @original_UserName IS NULL)) AND (([Timestamp] = @original_Timestamp) OR ([Timestamp] IS NULL AND @original_Timestamp IS NULL))`  Also, I have 3 parameters that come from other areas.  A value from a drop down list, the current time and date and the username.  These are form parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger.

It is *safer*, meaning that every time you delete a record from that history table (regardless of mechanism) it would still fire.

It is also easier to code as you don't have to put anything inside your .net code to handle it.

Finally, it is faster as there is zero network traffic involved.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend using a flag for deletion, and not actually delete the record...
to the gridview, you add an extra checkpoint that when selected it will trigger...like this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" SortExpression="ToBeDeleted">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtToBeDeleted" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ToBeDeleted") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%--<asp:Label ID="lblToBeDeleted" Width="20px" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ToBeDeleted") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkToBeDeleted" Width="20px" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("ToBeDeleted") %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkToBeDeleted_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle CssClass="overflowClass" HorizontalAlign="Center" Wrap="false" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

then in the code behind you handle the trigger:

```
protected void chkToBeDeleted_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)cb.NamingContainer;
            int id = (int)gvWines.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value;

            ListOfWine record = (from l in db.ListOfWines
                         where l.Id == id
                         select l).FirstOrDefault();

            //here you add the record to another table and then continue flagging the record for deletion

         record.ToBeDeleted = cb.Checked;
db.SaveChanges();
            gvWines.DataBind();
        }
```